# Cisco Wireless Migration

Tags: cisco, wireless, wlc, cisco-wireless

here is the scenario guys:

2 wlc (5508) in cluster, currently advertising 2 SSIDs, I want to advertise 2 more SSIDs with new vlans. 2 new SSIDs will be using their own RADIUS and NTP servers. Please help on how I can achieve this.

Note: I cant remove the old SSIDs untill we have rolled out the new ones and they are working properly.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: If you mean NTP servers for the clients (which I assume you do), NTP server addresses are handed out using DHCP, not part of the SSID.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

What Avery has said is correct. Assuming you mean NTP Servers for wireless clients, that would have to de bone through DHCP. You could only assign an NTP Server statically for the Wireless LAN Controller itself.

Regarding the new WLAN implementation, if you want to use new VLANs, new dynamic interfaces have to be created on the controller in order to achieve this. You would assign an available IP address within the subnet clients would grab an IP address from, indicate their gateway, DHCP Server and even put an 802.1q tag for the VLAN that must exist on the switch. This dynamic interface is then mapped to the new SSID for local access points. If you are using Flexconnect, local-switching for instance the configuration is different.

Make sure an available address pool is set for the new VLANs and that these two new VLANs are both permitted on your Switch-Controller trunk. That should get you started.